# Square wave output using java script code

Tags: javascript

Could any one please help me in generating the Square wave as the output when i give the input in 0's and 1's by using the java script.

it means when we give the input 10101010

the output should be increment the wave and decrementing ....

Comment: Please be more precise: a square wave as sound or as an image? Can you give an example of the end result?

Comment: Where is your efforts ???

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function in JavaScript that inverts a "square wave", passed as a string.

```
var squareWave = function (s) {
    var start = !parseInt(s[0]);
    var r = [];

    var len = s.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        r.push(start ? "1" : "0");
        start = !start;
    }

    return r.join("");
}
```

Testing the function

```
squareWave("101010101");
// returns "010101010"
squareWave("010101010");
// returns "101010101"
```